# DOMException when external link added to nav bar of Gymso template from Tooplate

Tags: javascript

We are using [this free template](https://www.tooplate.com/view/2119-gymso-fitness) that we have modified to the look of our site. We have run into a problem with the nav bar.  If we add an `http://` link we get a error:

> ( Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'http://test.com' is not a valid selector.)

From my reading on the web this is a problem with the  JS. How can I rectify it?

I have contacted Tooplate for help some time back but have had no response.

Comment: Can you try searching the code for `http://test.com` and put that in your post? Currently your question is very hard to answer from the information you have given..

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs due to an assumption within the gymso fitness template.

In the source code for the custom javascript (*custom.js*) for the template:

```js
// SMOOTHSCROLL NAVBAR
    $(function() {
      $('.navbar a, .hero-text a').on('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 49
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

the template assumes that the *href* (`.attr('href')`) property provided to a link in the navbar (`$('.navbar a, .hero-text a')`) should itself be a valid CSS selector. So if the *href* is *"#home"* then the `scrollTop` function will look for an element, using the `$` selector, on the template's page with `id="home"` (*which is the first section in the index.html*).

A *href* with a link as a value e.g *.com will result in said link being used as a selector but links are not valid CSS selectors.

#### Solution

If you need to add an external link to the navigation bar, you'll need to modify the smoothscroll function so the link is not targeted by it.

The instructions below assume you have access to, and can modify, the source code for the template. I also assume the source code is the same as that which is downloadable from the [gymso fitness template webpage](https://www.tooplate.com/view/2119-gymso-fitness).

*1. use a custom class for the link*

Note the use of the "external" class in the link.

*index.html*

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
...
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="http://test.com" class="nav-link smoothScroll external">Test link</a>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

*2. configure the smoothscroll function to not target external links*

*custom.js*

Note the addition of `:not(.external)` to the first selector.

```js
// SMOOTHSCROLL NAVBAR
    $(function() {
      $('.navbar a:not(.external), .hero-text a').on('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 49
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue.
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'http://test.com' is not a valid selector.
    at Object.getSelectorFromElement (file:///C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Website/2119_gymso_fitness/2119_gymso_fitness/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:1466)